# Как в October cms плагин Translate вывести на странице CMS ссылку на другую страницу

Tags: october

Помогите разобраться. Документацию к плагину смотрю но не понимаю. Как мне в коде страницы вывести ссылку на страницу контакта.

Стоит плагин Translate. Есть страница контакта на русском и английском. Пути к странице разные. Одинаковые пути не дает сделать сам октябрь. Мне нужно в cms странице вставить ссылку на контакт учитывая текущий язык. Если текущий язык английский то ссылка на контакт ведет на английскую версию контакта. Если текущий язык русский то ссылка ведет на русскую версию страницы контакт.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сделать ссылку с текущей локализацией сайта, достаточно в шаблоне TWIG писать ссылки так:

```
{{ 'page-file-name'|page }}
```

Если у вас страницы сделаны через StaticPage, то пишите так:

```
{{ 'page-file-name'|staticPage }}
```

Comment: Это хорошо, но ответы в виде ссылки не приветствуются на ru so, т.к. могут стать со временем нерабочими. Перенесите в ответ ключевые моменты из статьи по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Пока что сделал просто проверку. Если текущая локаль то вести на соответствующую версию страницы.

```
<a href="{% if  activeLocale  == 'et' %}/et/kontakt{% else %}/ru/kontakt-levelten{% endif %}">{{ 'Kirjuta meile'|_ }}</a>
```